# Automatic Firefox build on Windows(Jenkins)

Tags: windows, firefox, jenkins, build

I am trying to create a job for Jenkins to automatically build Firefox on Windows machine.

Is it possible to create a script(`.bat`, `.sh` or python) which starts `start-shell.bat` and executes `mach build` command  inside started shell window?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new freestyle job and then configure it.  After specifying where your source code repository is located in the SCM section.  Add a Window Batch Build step and specify the workspace-relative path to your .bat file that in turn calls the commands you want.